# Separate 404 page for Wordpress in subfolder

Tags: htaccess

I have two Wordpress websites on the same domain, one on the root and the other one in a subfolder. Everything works just fine but the 404 page of the sub-site; When I run into a 404 error on my subsite, instead of showing its own 404 page, it returns that of the parent folder.

Would you know how I can sort it out?

Thanks,

Comment: does this answer your qs? https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page if not, please post your htaccess

Comment: No, because I use permalinks. I use the default one.